# Literature on co- and contravariant formulation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, mathematical-physics, tensors, transformation

I am currently working on the topic of co- and contravariant formulation in physics. Unfortunately, my literature uses the topic very superficially. Is there any mathematical book with definition, theorem, lemma and proof, which brings me closer to the terms for transformations between systems?

Comment: Can you provide more context? Are you specifically asking about co- and contravariant vectors in quantum mechanics? Or are you talking about relativity theory? Also, do you want a mathematical or a physical explaination?

Comment: relativity theory.

Comment: There is a very comprehensive book on the differential geometry behind relativity theory, it is called 'The Geometry of Physics - An Introduction' by Theodore Frankel. It goes very deep, so you can see for yourself to which extend you want to understand the topic. The easiest answer to the question of co- and contravariance is given in the subchapter 'Vectors, 1-Forms, and Tensors'.